# Finding directory of eclipse being used

Tags: eclipse

I have multiple copies of eclipse and some of them are using projects from each other's workspace. When I try to find the eclipse I am using it shows up to use a different workspace but no other eclipse is using that workspace.
Is there some where I can find the directory from which I am running my present copy of eclipse ?
I tried searching on SO but couldn't find, if duplicate please point and close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the "Help" menu -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Configuration -> Look for `eclipse.home.location`

Answer (score 0):

If on windows try Filemon.
If using some plugins (i.e. one for tomcat) it maybe, that this has **one** config for **all** workspaces.